# Getting Errors running `go get github.com/hashicorp/vault/command`

Tags: go, dockerfile, hashicorp-vault

I have not had any errors get/install the package below up until 30/10/2019. Was something committed that caused it? How can i fix it? Thanks!

Command:

```
go get github.com/hashicorp/vault/command
```

Error:

```
 github.com/hashicorp/vault/builtin/logical/rabbitmq
/go/src/github.com/hashicorp/vault/builtin/logical/rabbitmq/path_role_create.go:100:23: client.UpdateTopicPermissionsIn undefined (type *rabbithole.Client has no field or method UpdateTopicPermissionsIn)
 /go/src/github.com/hashicorp/vault/builtin/logical/rabbitmq/path_role_create.go:100:66: undefined: rabbithole.TopicPermissions
```

go version: golang:1.12.9-alpine3.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the get command pulls the lattest version of the library your are using, but in your case you may want to use the previous version which was already working.

Based on here

https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/releases

You only have to import the version with this command

```
go get github.com/hashicorp/vault/command@v1.2.3
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for the solution I tried importing specific version. However I am getting error `go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode`

Comment: Can you try adding this `export GO111MODULE=on` to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`  more info https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules

Comment: Just turning on GO111MODULE isn't going to fix the issue. You need to `go mod init` and establish your project as a Go module properly.

Comment: @MauricioDeLaQuintana Sorry for getting back so late . Yes I had to set `GO111MODULE=on` and also as @Adrian mentioned had to do `go mod init .`